# is there a way to write the conditioning statement such that it prints hello grizzly

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to write a code so that it will print a greeting only to friendly bears and the code should work even if more bears are added to the dictionary.
the code is below

```
bears = {"Grizzly":"angry", "Brown":"friendly", "Polar":"friendly"}
for bear in bears: 
         if  bear == "friendly" :
                print("Hello,"+bear+"bear!")
         else:
                print("odd")
```

and the result is

```
odd
odd
odd
```

instead of it printing the greeting command under "if" since two keys have their values as friendly

Comment: You only iterate over the keys. You must ask "bears" for the value of the respective key.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```py
bears = {"Grizzly":"angry", "Brown":"friendly", "Polar":"friendly"}
for bear, personality in bears.items(): 
        if  personality == "friendly" :
            print("Hello,"+ bear +"bear!")
        else:
            print("odd")
```

Comment: This won't work either as the print should name the bear.

Comment: Ah, didnt see. Updated my answer

Comment: which way can i write the code such that it is only the line 3 that is edited or changed in the initial program and ' if ' is the starting function

Answer (score 0):

You can access both the key and value of each key value pair in the bears `dict` with the `items` method.

```
for bear, type_ in bears.items():
    if type_ == "friendly":
        print("Hello," + bear + "bear!")
    else:
        print("odd")
```

You can read more about tuple unpacking (which is how you assign values to `bear` and `type_` in the loop) [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/#Unpacking_in_a_for_loop).

*Updated*

You can also get the desired result without changing the loop variable by getting the value for each bear from the dictionary.

```
for bear in bears:
    if bears[bear] == "friendly":
        print("Hello," + bear + "bear!")
    else:
        print("odd")
```

Comment: other lines of code are okay except line 3  where we have if and if condition must be there in the code

Comment: I don't think i understand what you're asking for then. The above code prints `odd`, `Hello,Brownbear!`, `Hello,Polarbear!`. What is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: without changing the line 2 of the code which you changed, line 3 should be rewritten such that you print expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
bears = {"Grizzly":"angry", "Brown":"friendly", "Polar":"friendly"}
for bear in bears: 
         if  bears[bear] == "friendly" :
                print("Hello,"+bear+"bear!")
         else:
                print("odd")
```

the above is the answer because bears[bear] rep the value for each keys in the dictionary bears

Answer (score 0):

```
bears = {"Grizzly": "angry", "Brown": "friendly", "Polar": "friendly"}
for bear in bears:
    if bears[bear] == "friendly":
        bear = "friendly"
        print("Hello, "+bear+" bear!")
        break
    else:
        print("odd")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Plain code answers can almost always be improved by providing some explanation. Consider adding a sentence or two describing your solution. Also, your code will not run because some of the lines are not indented properly, so you should edit it and correct that. Be sure that any code you post runs properly when pasted directly into a Python interpreter.